# how can i execute a script in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

[db entry image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEkxU.jpg)
I have a database (an example of a record in the database is presented below) and I need to make sure that after 30 seconds the person with status = notverified is deleted from the database, how can this be done

I thought to implement this all through a Sql query assigned for use, but I did not like this idea because there is no such button on the site that would be pressed so often for it to work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a chronjob in mysql to do this. (If it is mysql here is a link:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html
)